# Google Script using Twilio's API running correctly but not returning correct value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, twilio

I'm having issues with a script that isn't outputting a correct value. It's otherwise working exactly as intended. Here's the whole script:

```
var statusColumnPos = [2,5]; // Position of status column
var searchColumn = 3 // Column C to search for number of entries

var dataTab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Booking Tracker"); // Get sheet by Name

var accountSID = "accountSID"; // account SID
var token = "accessToken"; // access token
var authorizationEncoded = "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(accountSID+":"+token);
var twillioNumber = "xxxxxxxxxx" // twillio number
var twillioAPI = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"+accountSID+"/Messages.json"



function getSmsDataFromCell(pos) {
  var cell = dataTab.getRange(pos, statusColumnPos[1]);
  var smsNumber = cell.offset(0, 1).getDisplayValue();
  var smsMessage = cell.offset(0,2).getDisplayValue();
  return [smsNumber, smsMessage];
} 

function statusChecker() {
  var searching = true;
  var count = 1;
  while(searching) {
    var value = dataTab.getRange(count,searchColumn);
    if (value.getValue() == "") {
      searching = false;
      break;
    } else {
      count++;
    }
  }
  var values = dataTab.getRange(statusColumnPos[0], statusColumnPos[1], count - 2);
  var arr = values.getValues();
  var newArr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {   
    if (arr[i][0] === "READY") {
    newArr = newArr.concat(i+2);
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    var data = getSmsDataFromCell(newArr[i]);
    dataTab.getRange(newArr[i], statusColumnPos[1] + 3).setValue("SENDING");
    var result = sendMessage(data[1], data[0], twillioNumber);
    if (result) {
      dataTab.getRange(newArr[i], statusColumnPos[1] + 3).setValue("SENT");
    } else {
      dataTab.getRange(newArr[i], statusColumnPos[1] + 3).setValue("FAILED")
    }
  }
}

function sendMessage(message, to, from) {
  var formData = {
    'Body': message,
    'From': from,
    'To': to,
  };
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'payload' : formData,
    'headers' : {
      'Authorization': authorizationEncoded
    }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(twillioAPI, options);
  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200 ) {
    return true
  } else {
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    return false
  };
}
```

The specific issue I'm having is that either this section is not returning TRUE:

```
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(twillioAPI, options);
  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200 ) {
    return true
  } else {
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    return false
  };
```

Or the following statement is not working as intended:

```
    var result = sendMessage(data[1], data[0], twillioNumber);
    if (result) {
      dataTab.getRange(newArr[i], statusColumnPos[1] + 3).setValue("SENT");
    } else {
      dataTab.getRange(newArr[i], statusColumnPos[1] + 3).setValue("FAILED")
    }
  }
}
```

SMS messages are sending as intended, but rather than resulting in SENT after sending, it's resulting in FAILED after sending. The structure seems sound to me so I don't want to "quick fix" it by swapping SENT/FAILED in my script. Is anyone seeing something that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Twilio's API documentation, a `POST` or `PUT` request returns the HTTP status code 200 only if a resource is updated, while it returns 201 if a new resource is created:

> Possible POST or PUT Response Status Codes
>
> - 200 OK: The request was successful, we updated the resource and the response body contains the representation.
> - 201 CREATED: The request was successful, we created a new resource and the response body contains the representation.

Source: [Creating or Updating Resources with the HTTP POST and PUT Methods](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/your-request-to-twilio#post).

When I tested this, status code 201 was returned and a text was successfully sent.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. THANK YOU!